# uploaded files by users in website are not showing when debug is false

Tags: django, nginx, hosting, cpanel, uwsgi

hey I've been working on my website for quite a while now and finally I was deploying it for production then I've faced with this problem that I can't server media when `DEBUG = FALSE` apparently Django doesn't serve media for you in production for some reasons,

IDK how to fix this and in my templates I've used this method to show different pictures that user have uploaded on website's database

```
<img src="{{site.logo.url}}" alt="logo" class="footer_logo">
```

now none of then show up  in website
here are my media and static roots in setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '../mywebsite/assets/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

# Additional locations of static files

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
```

I don't have a same problem with static files and I've almost tried all of the ways that others have recommended for same situation in other questions.

also I have no idea how to setup nginx but I have no problem with setting it up and learn about it if you guys can give me a guide an how to do it,
there was some tutorial on how to deploy django on Nginx with uWSGI but:

- first idk what is uWSGI
- and since I'm using cpanle idk if I can use uWSGI on it
- and also can I do all of these without changing any part of my website ? (like my Views, Models, Template and stuff)

sorry if any of these questions sounds stupid
It's my first time deploying a website, I'm learning
Thank you :)

Comment: check this posts https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04 , https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I voted to close this because it asks multiple questions in one post. It is also off-topic because it is not a programming question.   You can ask non-programming questions about your website at [webmasters.se].  When you ask there please just ask one question at a time.

Comment: thank you @AnkitTiwari